# Tool to copy IMAP folders from one server to another

Tags: imap

I need a Unix-based tool, such as a shell script or command-line program, to copy IMAP folders from one server to another. Ideally, the tool should copy all the folders for a single account (Inbox, Sent, Trash, and user-created folders) at once, rather than one folder at a time. It should preserve message dates. As an option, I'd like to be able to copy just a single IMAP folder.

Alternatively, is there a tool to copy an mbox file to an IMAP server? I have direct access to the mbox files in the filesystem, but not to the filesystem of the remote IMAP server.

Edit: Is there a way for a user to migrate their own questions to Server Fault?

Answer (score 6):

check also [imapsync](http://www.linux-france.org/prj/imapsync/), a great tool !!!

Comment: This program works like a charm!

Comment: imapsync is no longer free. It costs about $35. But it still works quite well.

Comment: great tool, it worth the money, i have some great experiences using it when it was free.

Comment: Happens to be free on macports: https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/mail/imapsync/Portfile

Comment: I found it on [GitHub](https://github.com/imapsync/imapsync) released under a "NO LIMIT PUBLIC LICENSE" in June of 2012.  It looks like a solid package; probably worth paying for it if it works for a big migration.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [offlineimap](http://software.complete.org/software/projects/show/offlineimap) - it can sync multiple imap servers, do server-to-maildir, and probably the other way around as well.

Comment: A +1 for offlineimap -- which has a Debian package, by the way, so you can easily `apt-get offlineimap`. A brilliant tool for replicating mailboxes.

Comment: It seems to work well. It's too bad the author thinks his documentation is all that. You better grab the example file from GIT: https://github.com/OfflineIMAP/offlineimap/blob/master/offlineimap.conf Of course the version that's in Squeeze is not the latest. So beware. It works for Gmail BTW.

Comment: To save others the chain of links, offlineimap has moved here: http://offlineimap.org/

Answer (score 3):

I'm a "fan" of these perl utils: http://www.athensfbc.com/imap_tools/ and have used them a fair bit

Comment: I am looking at this question by google search, but this answer really helped me, thanks a lot! +1